# Rotate/Spin a Sphere on a web page

Tags: javascript, css

I currently have a sphere shape but, I'm trying to think of a way on how to rotate it in a circle on my website this is my current code:

```
<style>
  b.ball {
      display: block;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      margin: 30px auto 0;
      background-color: #3b4ba3;
      border-radius: 50%;
      box-shadow: inset -25px -25px 40px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,220,.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,220,.2) 0%, transparent 100%);  
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,220,.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,220,.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
    }
<style>
<b class="ball"></b>
```

The code above puts a shape on the page.

How Would I rotate this sphere so it spins around? Not around the whole page but just in it's own area, not the entire page though. I've Googled it and I have not anything that particularly addresses this question that I've seen yet.

Comment: Do a Google Search for jQuery rotate/flip/spin plugins or CSS3 transitions.  They will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css-animations:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations

to animate a transform:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms

Just add in:

```
.ball {
    animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {

      from {

          transform:rotate(0deg);

      }

      to {

          transform:rotate(360deg);

      }
}
```

You'll need to use prefixes though, which I've included in the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/99bds/